# Why do i get a forbidden error when i change the symbolic-link for typo3?

Tags: apache, linux, ubuntu, permissions, typo3

I am currently using Typo3 8.7.32 and would like to update to the ELTS version 8.7.45. I have tried to install the new version manually via the Plesk web interface. When I change the sym-link in the last step or delete the old one and create a new one that points to the new version, I get a forbidden error as soon as I reload the page, both in the backend and in the frontend. The exact error is "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache server at xyz.at port 443".

Webserver: Apache
PHP-Version: 7.4.28
Database: MariaDB 10.3.34
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Comment: You need to look in Apache's `error_log` file (often located at `/var/log/apache2/error_log`) which should have extended information about the cause of the forbidden error.  This is usually caused by permissions problems on some folder or directory.  The log should tell you exactly which file or directory has the problem.  There is no way to answer that without having access to the log file, so we really can't help you unless you include it in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will take a look at the log file.